# java simulation of a card dealer - ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java

I am having trouble executing my code and unable to pinpoint exactly the source of the error or why and maybe someone might be able to take a look and provide me with some feedback if possible.

**Error message:**

```
51
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
3 of Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts, Spades
    at javacards.Card.toString(Card.java:15)
    at javacards.CardRun.main(CardRun.java:15)
```

**CardRun Class:**

```
public class CardRun {

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Deck deck = new Deck();
    Card C;

    System.out.println(deck.getTotalCards());

    while(deck.getTotalCards() != 0)
    {
        C = deck.drawFromDeck();
        System.out.println(C.toString());
    }
}
```

**Card Class**

```
public class Card {
    private int card, suit;
    private static String[] suits = {"Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts, Spades"};
    private static String[] cards = {"Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King"};

    Card(int suit, int card)
    {
        this.card = card;
        this.suit = suit;
    }

    public @Override String toString()
    {
        return cards[card] + " of " + suits[suit];
    }

    public int getCard()
    {
        return card;
    }

    public int getSuit()
    {
        return suit;
    }
}
```

**Deck Class**

```
public class Deck {

private Card[]cards;
int i;

Deck()
{
    i = 51; 
    cards = new Card[52];
    int x = 0;
    for(int a=0; a<=3; a++)
    {
        for(int b=0; b<=12; b++)
        {
            cards[x] = new Card(a,b);
            x++;
        }
    }
}

public Card drawFromDeck()
{
    Random generator = new Random();
    int index = 0;

    index = generator.nextInt(i);
    Card temp = cards[index];
    cards[index] = cards[i];
    cards[i] = null;
    i--;
    return temp;
}

public int getTotalCards()
{
    return i;
}
}
```

Comment: The exception message should give you a *stack trace*, i.e. the sequence of nested calls that caused the error.  Alternatively, you could run your code in the debugger, which would allow you to inspect variable values at the point of the crash.

Comment: the value of  *card* inside your cards array is bigger than the total amount of cards in your array. (--> this line return cards[card]) You're basically trying to return the 10 th card, while you only have 9. (for example)

Comment: Side suggestion: Use an `enum` for the suits. Perhaps for the card values as well.

Comment: @SimonAndreForsberg thanks for the suggestion i will put it under consideration.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This array:

```
private static String[] suits = {"Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts, Spades"};
```

only contains one item - you probably meant:

```
private static String[] suits = {"Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades"};
```